# functions.php mistakenly deleted

Tags: functions, themes

I've mistakenly deleted the **`functions.php`** file of my Twenty Sixteen WordPress Theme running the command below:

```
rm  /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php
```

The Twenty Sixteen Theme is my currently active theme and as such, my WordPress site is no longer accessible as it used to be *(ref. screenshot below)*.

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can restore it unless you are using any code versioning tool like git or svn and have your last changes committed there.

Comment: If there was no change in `functions.php` file then you can simply download the theme from [here](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/) and copy paste the file from downloaded zip to above path.

Comment: Backups:  saving you from mistakes such as this by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your site, you should get another [**`functions.php`**](https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/functions.php).

As such, you can get that from your most recent and operational backup and upload it unto the location of the mistakenly deleted one.

In case you don't have a backup, your last option will be to download a fresh copy of your [theme](https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentysixteen.1.3.zip); once that done, extract and upload the **`functions.php`** file it contains unto the location of the one you've mistakenly deleted from your server.

In the later case (should you have edited directly your **`functions.php`** - *which is not a recommended practice*), you cannot recover any previous modifications performed on the file.

*Should you consider editing the Twenty Sixteen WordPress Theme or any other one from the [WordPress Repository](https://wordpress.org/themes/) or any other source, I will recommend you create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of the theme you intended to use for that purpose, rather than editing the actual theme directly.*

Answer (score 0):

You can always re-download the Twenty Sixteen theme from the official [**Theme Directory**](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/) and restore the functions.php file. You'll lose any edits you have made to the previous file